# IIS Express won't run on TFS Build Server

Tags: unit-testing, iis, tfs, tfsbuild

I am facing a problem in the setting-up of the continuous integration on my project (*C# - Web - Visual Studio 2013 - TFS 2013*).

I have a custom build definition (*Gated Check-In*) which runs tests before each commit on the TFS Server.

To realize the tests I have to launch 4 IIS Express sites, things I do with command line.

It is well working in local on my computer but when I use the same command throught the *Gated Check-In* build, the IIS Express window open and instantly close itself. And obviously, the sites aren't running.

If I run the same command on the Build Server from command line, it works well, like in local and I can run the tests without any problem.

Does anyone of you ever faced a similary problem in the past ?

Have a nice day

Leop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours of research, I can self-answer my question...

The right way to be able to launch an IIS Express site (or more) on a Build Server is to use the *xcopy* options to copy/paste the files of the *Binaries* folder into the *Sources\YourProjectName* folder.

I did it with this command line in the *post-build event* options (right click - properties (on the main node of the project)):

```
xcopy /y "$(TargetDir)*.*" "..\Sources\*YourProjectName*\bin\" /r /s
```

Have a nice day

Leop

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 choices that you have (probably more than 2, but these are the two I use).

1. Automate the deployment of your website to IIS and run that during your build before your tests
2. Use attributes on your unit test to automatically fire up the in-process web server

The 2nd option is probably what you're looking for.  You can use a combination of attributes on your test cases to indicate that certain web sites/services need to be running for that test (mainly the AspNetDevelopmentServer attribute).

You can read the MSDN docs on this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Hello Dylan Smith, thank you for your help.
By "Use attributes on your unit test to..." you would said that I have to use [AssemblyInitialise] with Process myProcess.Start to run IISExpress.exe with the rights arguments ?
If yes, it's what is not working currently.
About your link, I haven't .aspx on my project and I can't add it. I just have a .asax file.
And if it could help, my web application is a MVC one.